# Update smart-table by WebSocket

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, smart-table

There are 2 tabs in the container.
Each tab has a smart-table in it.

1. User clicks on the tab.

   ```
   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
       var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
       var relatedTarget = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href")
       if (target == "#tab1") {
           Scopes.get('tab1').get_records();
       } else if (target == "#tab2") {
           Scopes.get('tab2').get_records();
       }
   })
   ```
2. Call server to get all record and display on the table.(only first time)

   ```
   $scope.got_tab1_records = false;
   $scope.get_records = function () {
       if($scope.got_tab1_records) return;
       var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
       var url = Flask.url_for('recorder.record_list', {info_type: 1, from_date: today, to_date: today});
       $http.get(url).success(
           function(data){
               $scope.tab1_records = data;
               $scope.safe_tab1_records = [].concat($scope.tab1_records);
               $scope.got_tab1_records = true;
           }
       ).error(function(response){
           alert(response);
       }).finally(function (){
       });
   }
   ```
3. If there is a new record, get the record from WebSocket.

   ```
   var url = "ws://" + window.location.href.replace(/https?:\/\//,'').replace(/\/.*/,'') + "/ws";
   var ws = new WebSocket(url);
   ws.onerror = function (e) {
       alert(e);
       console.log("WebSocket Error" + e);
       console.log(e);
   }
   ws.onclose = function () {
       document.getElementById("logo").style.color = "gray";
   }
   ws.onmessage = function (e) {
       var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
       $scope.append_record(obj.state, obj.record);
   }
   $scope.append_record = function(info_type, record){
       if (info_type == 1) {
           Scopes.get('tab1').unshift_record(record);
       } else if (info_type == 2) {
           Scopes.get('tab2').safe_tab1_records.unshift(JSON.parse(record));
       }
   };
   ```
4. Unshift the record on the st-safe-src and refresh the table.

   ```
   $scope.unshift_record = function (record) {
       $scope.safe_tab1_records.unshift(JSON.parse(record));
   };
   ```

My question is the step 4 did not refresh the table.
Only if I click on another tab then click on the original tab.
But, click on the button in the tab1 it will unshift a record and display on the first row of the table.

```
    $scope.addRandomItem = function addRandomItem() {
        $scope.safe_tab1_records.unshift({_datetime:'2017-02-23', _device:'1'});
    };
```

Also, I have a question.
Why the st-pagesizelist="10,50,100,1000" did not work ?

I have [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wlyuHVUQHNm2RcVNGYJk?p=preview) to show this problem. But I don't know how to simulate WebSocket.

Html:

```
<div id="right_container" style="position: absolute; width: 38%; height: calc(100% - 107px); right: 0px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active" ng-controller="tab1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 42px); top: 42px;">
            <button type="button" ng-click="addRandomItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                </i> Add random item
            </button>
            <table st-table="tab1_records" st-safe-src="safe_tab1_records" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #2A66AB; color: white;">
                    <th>time</th>
                    <th>device</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: white;">
                    <th><input st-search="time" class="form-control" placeholder="time search ..." type="text" /></th>
                    <th><input st-search="device" class="form-control" placeholder="device search ..." type="text" /></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="background-color: white;">
                <tr ng-repeat="record in tab1_records">
                    <td>{$record._datetime$}</td>
                    <td>{$record._device$}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
                            <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7" st-pagesizelist="10,50,100,1000"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade" ng-controller="tab2" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 42px); top: 42px;">
            <table st-table="tab2_records" st-safe-src="safe_tab2_records" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #2A66AB; color: white;">
                    <th>time</th>
                    <th>device</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: white;">
                    <th><input st-search="time" class="form-control" placeholder="time search ..." type="text" /></th>
                    <th><input st-search="device" class="form-control" placeholder="device search ..." type="text" /></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="background-color: white;">
                <tr ng-repeat="record in tab2_records">
                    <td>{$record._datetime$}</td>
                    <td>{$record._device$}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
                            <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7" st-pagesizelist="10,50,100,1000"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="/statics/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/statics/scripts/Smart-Table-2.1.8/smart-table.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('map', ['smart-table']);
app = angular.module('map').config(function ($httpProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('scope.stored', function (event, data) {
        console.log("scope.stored", data);
    });
});
app.controller('tab1', ['$scope', '$http', 'Scopes', function ($scope, $http, Scopes) {
    Scopes.store('tab1', $scope);
    $scope.got_tab1_records = false;
    $scope.get_records = function () {
        if($scope.got_tab1_records) return;
        var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
        var url = Flask.url_for('recorder.record_list', {info_type: 1, from_date: today, to_date: today});
        $http.get(url).success(
            function(data){
                $scope.tab1_records = data;
                $scope.safe_tab1_records = [].concat($scope.tab1_records);
                $scope.got_tab1_records = true;
            }
        ).error(function(response){
            alert(response);
        }).finally(function (){
        });
    }
    $scope.addRandomItem = function addRandomItem() {
        $scope.safe_tab1_records.unshift({_datetime:'2017-02-23', _device:'1'});
    };
    $scope.unshift_record = function (record) {
        $scope.safe_tab1_records.unshift({_datetime:'2017-02-23', _device:'2'});
    };
    $scope.get_records();
}]);
app.controller('tab2', ['$scope', '$http', 'Scopes', function ($scope, $http, Scopes) {
    Scopes.store('tab2', $scope);
    $scope.got_tab2_records = false;
    $scope.get_records = function () {
        if($scope.got_tab2_records) return;
        var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
        var url = Flask.url_for('recorder.record_list', {info_type: 2, from_date: today, to_date: today});
        $http.get(url).success(
            function(data){
                $scope.tab2_records = data;
                $scope.safe_tab2_records = [].concat($scope.tab2_records);
                $scope.got_tab2_records = true;
            }
        ).error(function(response){
            alert(response);
        }).finally(function (){
        });
    };
    $scope.unshift_record = function (record) {
        $scope.safe_tab1_records.unshift(JSON.parse(record));
    };
}]);
app.controller('preview', ['$scope', '$http', 'Scopes', function ($scope, $http, Scopes) {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
        var relatedTarget = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href")
        if (target == "#tab1") {
            Scopes.get('tab1').get_records();
        } else if (target == "#tab2") {
            Scopes.get('tab2').get_records();
        }
    })
    $scope.append_record = function(info_type, record){
        if (info_type == 1) {
            Scopes.get('tab1').unshift_record(record);
        } else if (info_type == 2) {
            Scopes.get('tab2').safe_tab1_records.unshift(JSON.parse(record));
        }
    };
    var url = "ws://" + window.location.href.replace(/https?:\/\//,'').replace(/\/.*/,'') + "/ws";
    var ws = new WebSocket(url);
    ws.onerror = function (e) {
        alert(e);
        console.log("WebSocket Error" + e);
        console.log(e);
    }
    ws.onclose = function () {
        document.getElementById("logo").style.color = "gray";
    }
    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
        $scope.append_record(obj.state, obj.record);
    }
}]);

app.factory('Scopes', function ($rootScope) {
    var mem = {};
    return {
        store: function (key, value) {
            $rootScope.$emit('scope.stored', key);
            mem[key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return mem[key];
        }
    };
});
</script>
```